# Reactive Extensions converting from IObservable to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

Given an Observable that will start pushing events once Subscribe is called. How can the sequence be converted into an IEnumerable.

In 2010 Jon Skeet wrote about his first impressions of RX and wrote this, which would be equivalent to what I need.

```
public static List<T> ToList<T>(this IObservable<T> source) 
{ 
    List<T> ret = new List<T>(); 
    source.Subscribe(x => ret.Add(x)); 
    return ret; 
}
```

https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/01/16/first-encounters-with-reactive-extensions/

While this solution would work it seems like there should be a better way.

What we're really interested in is the ability to `await` the observable in a way that behaves similarly to Subscribe.

```
await observable.ToList()
```

However, this doesn't seem to work for me.

I've also looked into these two methods

```
observable.ToEnumerable
observable.Next
```

*A little more information*

I plan to use this to write some unit tests.

1. I'm using a `ReplaySubject` and performing a sequence of actions with a test substitute.
2. Calls to the substitute are recorded via `OnNext`.
3. I can get the list of calls and Assert they are correct.

Comment: Jon Skeet's article was written in 2010, when Rx was just a research project and `async/await` were two years in the future. [By 2011](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh211848(v%3dvs.103)) Observable had its own `ToList()` extension method

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so you can change IObservable<T> to IObservable<IList<T>>
`IObservable<IList<TSource>> ToList<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source)`
[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh211848(v=vs.103))
And Daniel is asking about IObservable<T> to IEnumerable<T> conversion

Comment: @lerthe61 check Shlomo's answer that shows how to do just that. `ToEnumerable()` offers a blocking alternative.   Jon Skeet's article was written back when Rx was a research project and doesn't apply anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly Mr Skeet's implementation is pretty woeful. It doesn't block so will only pump values into the list if the source happens to be a replay subject (or similar). So for most Observable Sequences, this would just return an empty list. 
I am sure Jon knows that, but maybe got lost in translation.

The `ToList()` is what you want, so I assume that perhaps you are not completing? If you only want a known number of elements, then `Take(x).ToList()` will suffice instead.

Comment: I strongly suggest editing this answer. Jon Skeet's article was written in 2010, when there was no `async/await`. Reactive Extensions was just a research project back then. No `ToList()`,

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**:

If you're unable to complete the stream as described below, then using `await` will wait interminably. I would test in some other manner. You can look at Nuget Package `Microsoft.Reactive.Testing`, which contains some powerful testing tools. Or just using `Subscribe` and asserting in there.

---

`await` awaits for the observable to finish or error out. You probably just need to add an `OnCompleted` call to your `ReactiveSubject` and you should be fine. The following code works for me:

```
var rs = new ReplaySubject<int>();

rs.OnNext(1);
rs.OnNext(2);
rs.OnNext(3);
rs.OnCompleted();
var l = await rs.ToList();

//l is equivalent to  new List<int>() {1, 2, 3};
```

Comment: I just realised I have no way to complete the stream

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: It doesn't appear that it's possible to assert in the Subscribe method

Comment: I also don't need a list, I just need the first n events if that helps, so I might be able to say take(3).toList()